# Restrict Content Editor Language Dropdown Options

Tags: content-editor

I am trying to only display certain languages for Editors in the Sitecore Content Editor Language dropdown/selector.

In the access viewer, it shows the permission correctly for the editors. (i.e. only have language read/write permission to the few languages in /system/languages for the editors). But, in content editor, it still display all the language options in the language selector.

When a language without permission selected, it displays "The security settings for the current language prevent you from seeing this item." warning.

But what I need is totally remove the languages without permission from the editor dropdown.

Any idea/help on this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the Languages Gallery form (`Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Languages.GalleryLanguagesForm`). The following code in the `OnLoad` method is expected to skip rendering languages if a user hasn't got *Read* access rights granted.

```
foreach (Language language in languages)
{
  Item languageItem = LanguageManager.GetLanguageItem(language, item.Database);
  // this is ALLWAYS null if a user hasn't got Read access
  if (languageItem != null)
  {
    if (!languageItem.Access.CanRead())
    {
      continue;
    }

...
```

#### Problem

The problem is in the `if (languageItem != null)` statement which is expected to be `true` to skip a language, but in fact it's always `false` because the user *hasn't got* the read access and cannot read the language item.

#### Workaround

You may try [override the entire form code-behind class](https://sdn.sitecore.net/scrapbook/customize%20an%20xml%20control.aspx) and skip languages if there are no corresponding language items found:

```
foreach (Language language in languages)
{
  Item languageItem = LanguageManager.GetLanguageItem(language, item.Database);
  // do not render language if it cannot be read
  if (languageItem == null)
  {
    continue;
  }

  if (!languageItem.Access.CanRead())
  {
    continue;
  }
```

The side effect of that is  that all the languages from the `core` database that have not been duplicated in `master` will disappear. That's happening because in the code above the `LanguageManager` tries to read and check *availability* for languages from the `item.Database` only (which is `master`):

```
LanguageManager.GetLanguageItem(language, item.Database);
```

Comment: There's also an official fix for that here: 8.1.2 -  https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.141831/tree/v8.1.2 /  8.2.2 - https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.141831/tree/v8.2.2